# Android sharing Intent choser - Filter apps based on accepted file size

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-sharing

In my application I use the following code to share multiple video files to an application of the users choice. This works fine but I would like to dynamically limit the choices to apps that can handle the filesize. For instance gmail limits it attachments to 25MB on my device, while google drive does not.

Is it possible to do this?

If it helps here is my code.

```
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
        for(File f : files.getFiles()){ //files is an array of the files to share
            Uri mp4Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.myfileproviderauthority", f);
            uris.add(mp4Uri);
        }

        sharingIntent.setType("video/mp4");
        sharingIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "toMe@company.com" });
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Video");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Checkout the video!");
        sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share video clip");

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = 
             context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(chooser, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            for(Uri uri : uris){
                //TODO: Caution: Calling setFlags() is the only way to securely grant access to your files using temporary access permissions.
                // Avoid calling Context.grantUriPermission() method for a file's content URI, since this method grants access that you can only revoke by calling Context.revokeUriPermission().
                context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
        }
        context.startActivity(chooser);
```

Comment: Nice question. Sorry to say, but it looks too custom request to be possible.

Comment: @RevakoOA That was my fear. But could it be possible to filter out Social apps and email apps from my end, without naming specific apps?